# Can't get my email value from the form

Tags: forms, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, httprequest

I am trying to get email from my form, the post request is good is the firebug window, but then i can't get it properly, even if my variables are set to the name "email", my code is looking for "username" parameters in the request (which is null btw) and put its value in the variable i want to sent to the DB.

I 'am masking myself if my eclipse is not corrupted because of these non updating variables.... I clear my tomcat (7.0.59) each time a try the code and i've already tried to uninstall tomcat and re-install it. 
Do you have any leads ?

Here is my total code

```
package com.isep.connexion.model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import com.isep.eleve.model.Eleve;
import com.isep.metier.Users;

public final class ConnexionForm {
    private static final String CHAMP_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String CHAMP_PASS   = "password";  
    private String              resultat;
    private Map<String, String> erreurs      = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getResultat() {
        return resultat;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getErreurs() {
        return erreurs;
    }

    public Users connecterUser( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        /* getting data from form */
        String email = getValeurChamp( request, CHAMP_EMAIL );
        String password = getValeurChamp( request, CHAMP_PASS );

        Users eleve = new Users();

        /* email validation. */
        try {
            validationEmail(email);
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            setErreur( CHAMP_EMAIL, e.getMessage() );
        }
        eleve.setEmail(email);

        /* PW validation */
        try {
            validationMotDePasse(password);
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            setErreur( CHAMP_PASS, e.getMessage() );
        }
        eleve.setPassword(password);

        /* setting connexion result */
        if ( erreurs.isEmpty() ) {
            resultat = "Succès de la connexion.";
        } else {
            resultat = "Échec de la connexion.";
        }

        return eleve;
    }

    /**
     * Valide l'adresse email saisie.
     */
    private void validationEmail( String email ) throws Exception {
         if ( email != null ) {
                if ( !email.matches( "([^.@]+)(\\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\\.)+([^.@]+)" ) ) {
                    throw new Exception( "Merci de saisir une adresse mail valide." );
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception( "Merci de saisir une adresse mail." );
            }
    }

    /**
     * check email syntax
     */
    private void validationMotDePasse( String password ) throws Exception {
        if ( password != null ) {
            if ( password.length() < 3 ) {
                throw new Exception( "Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 3 caractères." );
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception( "Merci de saisir votre mot de passe." );
        }
    }

    /*
     * getting error with the name of the input
     */
    private void setErreur( String champ, String message ) {
        erreurs.put( champ, message );
    }

    /*
     * getting value from the input
     * 
     */
    private static String getValeurChamp( HttpServletRequest request, String nomChamp ) {
        String valeur = request.getParameter( nomChamp );
        if ( valeur == null || valeur.trim().length() == 0 ) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return valeur;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the controller part

```
package com.isep.connexion.controlleur;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.isep.connexion.model.ConnexionForm;
import com.isep.eleve.model.Eleve;
import com.isep.metier.Demo;
import com.isep.metier.Users;


 // Servlet implementation class Connexion

@WebServlet("/Connexion")
public class ConnexionController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String ATT_USER = "eleve";
    public static final String ATT_FORM = "form";
    public static final String ATT_SESSION_USER = "sessionUser";
    public static final String LOGIN = "/view/connex.jsp";
    public static final String ETUDIANT = "/view/AccueilEtudiant.jsp";
    public static final String TUTEUR = "/view/ProfilTuteur.jsp";



     // @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()

    public ConnexionController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


     // @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, //HttpServletResponse response)

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

//      heading the jsp
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(LOGIN).forward( request, response );
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ConnexionForm form = new ConnexionForm();
        Users eleve = form.connecterUser( request );
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        request.setAttribute( ATT_FORM, form );
        request.setAttribute( ATT_USER, eleve );

        if ( form.getErreurs().isEmpty() && eleve.getPassword().equals(demo.chargerMDP(eleve.getEmail())) ) {
            session.setAttribute( ATT_SESSION_USER, eleve );
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( ETUDIANT ).forward( request, response );
        } else {

            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( LOGIN ).forward( request, response );
            session.setAttribute( ATT_SESSION_USER, null );
        }



        if ( form.getErreurs().isEmpty() ) {

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

and here is my JSP code :

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/GAPP/ressources/css/lastcss.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Gestion APP</title>
</head>
<body class="connexion">

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content modal-md">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="text-center ">Connexion</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="col-md-12 center-block" method="post"
                    action="connexion">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"
                            value="<c:out value="${param.email}"/>"
                            class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="email" required
                            autofocus /><br> <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['email']}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password"
                            class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="password" required /><br>
                        <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['password']}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success"
                            value="login"><br>
                        <p class="${empty form.erreurs ? 'succes' : 'erreur'}">${form.resultat}</p>
                        <p>${sessionScope.sessionUser.email}</p> <!-- pour voir que la session est détruite -->
                        <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Register</a></span> <span><a
                            href="#">Mot de passe oublié</a></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: I can't achieve to get the email the user put in the form into on the right variable, my email variable is always null and i can't find why

Comment: the name of servlet is Connexion ? 
and in the form you put  action="connexion"

Comment: the controler is ConnexionControlleur, the other one is ConnexionModel and the JSP is connex